# I am trying to post data in stream parameter of WCF method from Jquery. But not working

Tags: android, jquery, rest, wcf, service

I have made a WCF service method to upload the file on the server and wanted to pass other relevant values as well along with stream but from jquery i am unable to short out that how can i do that.

Here is my WCF method.

```
    public void UploadCustomFile(RemoteFileInfo request)
    {

        string FilePath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Downloads"), "abc");
        int length = 0;
        using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            int readCount;
            var buffer = new byte[8192];
            while ((readCount = request.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                writer.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                length += readCount;
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is my RemoteFileInfo Class :

```
[DataContract]
    public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string FileName;

        [DataMember]
        public long Length;

        [DataMember]
        public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (FileByteStream != null)
            {
                FileByteStream.Close();
                FileByteStream = null;
            }
        }   
    }
```

and Here is the jquery+html,

```
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" value="" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button id="btnUpload" onclick="UploadFile()">
            Upload</button>
    </div>
    <button id="btnDownload" onclick="DownloadFile()">
        Download</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function UploadFile() {
            // grab your file object from a file input
            fileData = document.getElementById("fileUpload").files[0];
            var data = new FormData();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:1398/AristMobileService.svc/UploadFile',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false, // Don't process the files
                contentType: "application/octet-stream", // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('successful..');
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    //alert('Some error Occurred!');
                }
            });

        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Also Here is the json request Body which i suppose to use while posting the data from jquery side,

```
{
    "FileByteStream":{
        "__identity":{
            "__identity":{
                "__identity":null
            }
        }
    },
    "FileName":"String content",
    "Length":9223372036854775807
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't even sending the file...you are sending an empty [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) object.

As for including both you need to use `FormData.append(key, value)` to set each part of what you want to send be it file or data

you can also pass a whole form element into `new FormData(formelement)`

Comment: How can i form valid json to post in stream parameter ?